# Couldn't open CUDA library cublas64_80.dll

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

1.I have Installed CUDA Toolkit 8.0 
2.Downloaded cuDNN 5.1 
3.merged the files in cuDNN 5.1/cuda with C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0 bin,include,lib

4.set new path variables
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64
5.Installed GPU version of TensorFlow 1.0.0 (my code only works in 1.0.0) using the following command
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.0.0

Now when I run my chatbot.py code in spyder I am facing these errors

```
    An error ocurred while starting the kernel
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library cublas64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:2294] Unable to load cuBLAS DSO.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:3517] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library cufft64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_fft.cc:344] Unable to load cuFFT DSO.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:135] successfully opened CUDA library nvcuda.dll locally
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:126] Couldn't open CUDA library curand64_80.dll
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_rng.cc:338] Unable to load cuRAND DSO.
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.62
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 4.00GiB
Free memory: 3.30GiB
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 0: Y 
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) ‑> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
F c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release‑win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_blas.cc:268] Check failed: s.ok() could not find cublasCreate_v2 in cuBLAS DSO; dlerror: cublasCreate_v2 not found
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happen if you have not installed the patch of the CUDA 8.0. Please install the Patch 2 from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive